# Does travis-ci.org support pm2？

Tags: node.js, continuous-integration, autotest, pm2

I set up a nodejs auto test with travis-ci.org。I need to set up a server to support static files.I want to know if trvis-ci support pm2:)

Or，is there any way to record a server`s pid。

like pm2 do:

```
pm2 start app.js

pm2 stop app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install pm2 on travis. To do that, you need to change your .travis.yml:

before_script: